# Dygraph ticker problems - can't get date

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am trying to plot some data from OpenTSDB in Dygraph. I have the query working and I can plot the data. However when I try and set the x ticker property (as below) I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  dygraph-combined.js:2
Dygraph.numberValueFormatter                     dygraph-combined.js:2
Dygraph.numberAxisLabelFormatter                 dygraph-combined.js:2
Dygraph.getDateAxis                              dygraph-combined.js:2
Dygraph.dateTicker                               dygraph-combined.js:2
Dygraph.addXTicks_                               dygraph-combined.js:2
Dygraph.drawGraph_                               dygraph-combined.js:2
Dygraph.predraw_                                 dygraph-combined.js:2
Dygraph.start_                                   dygraph-combined.js:2
Dygraph.__init__                                 dygraph-combined.js:2
Dygraph                                          dygraph-combined.js:2
```

The code that I'm using is:

```
new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv2"), obj[0].dps, {
  labels: [ "Date", "Fuel Level" ],
  ylabel: 'Fuel Level', 
  xlabel: 'Date',
  axes: {
    x: {
      valueFormatter: Dygraph.dateString_,
      ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker }
    },
  xValueParser: function(x) { return parseInt(x); }
});
```

If I take out the `ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker` option, then the graph plots perfectly and the value that shows up when I hover over the graph is the correct date and time but the tick values are unix timestamps. What is the issue here?

Comment: hi bteres! what type of graph are u using for Dygraph? http://dygraphs.com/gallery/

Comment: Hi Papouche! Just a standard graph. Not trying to do anything special yet but the data is an array.